# Greatest possible number of primes between 1 and $x$

Tags: prime-numbers

Background: I'm making a program in java to calculate all the primes between 1 and any given number ($\pi(x)$). I want to create an array that will contain all the numbers, but resizing an array takes time. The solution I came up with was to initialize the array with more possible elements than I know I will need. The problem with that is that I don't know the greatest possible number of elements I will need.

[This](http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.shtml) page show how to approximate $\pi(x)$ with $\frac{x}{\log x - 1}$, but I want to find a fairly simple function such that $f(x)$ is always $\ge \pi(x)$. I considered using something similar to $1.1(\frac{x}{\log x - 1})$, but there is a possibility that $\pi(x) - \frac{x}{\log x - 1}$ increases exponentially.

Does anybody know of an equation for $f(x)$ so that for every value of $x$, $f(x)$ is greater than—but still as close as possible to—$\pi(x)$?

Comment: How are we defining "close to"?

Comment: @DennisMeng edited to "as close as possible to"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page you linked to, you find a [result by Dusart](http://primes.utm.edu/references/refs.cgi/Dusart99) that for all $x>1$
$$  \pi(x) <\frac x{\ln x}\cdot\left(1 + \frac{1.2762}{\ln x}\right) $$
Sine also $\pi(x)>\frac{x}{\ln x}$ this bound is close to $\pi(x)$ in the sense that the relative error tends to $0$ as $x$ gets large.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I saw `if x>598` but didn't see `(The upper bound holds for all x > 1.)`. Silly me, and thanks again!